# Search number from 'txt A' and replace into csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have been trying this many ways, but still cannot achieved what I want. Sorry i'm still learning.

What I want is like this:

**File A.txt**

```
5844
6069
6303
6309
```

**File B.txt**

```
// some comment
// some  explanation
100,5,3,8,,,
500,5,44,8,,,
//2500,5,2,8,,,
2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
6069,5,4,8,,,
```

I want to change the searched number from A.txt and comment out the line in B.txt.
sometimes the searched number may appear in another column, so it will only change the first column.

**Result:**

```
// some comment
// some  explanation
100,5,3,8,,,
500,5,44,8,,,
2500,5,2,8,,,
2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
//5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
//6069,5,4,8,,,
```

I tried and sometimes it got mess up and changed the other column also.
Then I used something like this, its very long and not easy to modified,

```
awk -F ',' '/^5844/ && $1="5844"{$1="//5844"}1' b.txt > c.txt; cp c.txt ba.txt; rm -rf b.txt; mv ba.txt b.txt
```

and it's also sometimes remove the ',' separator.

Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: General note on safety: _never_ run `rm -rf` if it isn't necessary. To delete a regular file, you don't need `-r` or `-f` so just run `rm` alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F , 'FNR==NR { data[$1]=1; next } $1 in data { $0 = "//" $0 }; 1' 'File A.txt' 'File B.txt'
500,5,4,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
2121,5,4,8,,,
//5844,5,4,5844,,,
//6069,5,4,8,,,
```

What I'm doing here is first reading in the numbers from `File A.txt` as keys in the associative array `data`.  I then test each first field from `File B.txt` to see whether it's a key in `data` or not.  If it is, I prepend `//` to the current line.  All lines, whether modified or not, are then printed.

The `FNR==NR` test will only ever be true while reading from the first file on the command line, and the block finishes with `next`.  This means that the first block is executed for the first file only, while the second block is executed for the second file, if the first field is a key in the `data` array.

The `1` at the end triggers the output and could be replaced by `{ print }`.

The above will only *add* `//` to the lines in the second files matching the numbers in the first file.  To also *remove* `//` from lines *not* matched (i.e. to handle your updated question):

```
$ cat 'File B.txt'
// some comment
// some  explanation
100,5,3,8,,,
500,5,44,8,,,
//2500,5,2,8,,,
2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
6069,5,4,8,,,
```

```
$ awk -F , 'FNR==NR { data[$1]=1; next } FNR > 2 { if ($1 in data) $0 = "//" $0; else sub("^//","") }; 1' 'File A.txt' 'File B.txt'
// some comment
// some  explanation
100,5,3,8,,,
500,5,44,8,,,
2500,5,2,8,,,
2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
//5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
//6069,5,4,8,,,
```

The `awk` command assumes that you want to pass the first two lines of `File B.txt` through unchanged (this is what the `FNR > 2` test takes care of).  The `FNR > 2` block tests whether the number is a key in `data` or not, and if it is, the line is commented out, but if it isn't, any `//` at the start of the line is removed using `sub()`.

Instead of `FNR > 2` you could use `/^\/\/ /` to test for a comment at the top of the file. This would require that all such comments always start with `//` followed by a space.

The special variables `NR` and `FNR` holds the number of lines read so far in total (`NR`) and in the current file (`FNR`).

---

The commas would "disappear" if I changed only the first field with `$1 = "//" $1` as that would re-form the record using the current value of `OFS` (a space by default). You could prevent this by using `BEGIN { OFS=FS }`, which would set `OFS` to the comma character (or whatever character you use with `-F` on the command line).

Comment: Does it need to be `data[$1]=1; next`? Wouldn't just `data[$1]; next` be sufficient?

Comment: @guest Possibly, if you're tired of typing, yes. I _think_ that should work, but as I'm not 100% certain it works everywhere I opted for setting a value.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, i think my question is a bit wrong, should i change the main post?
file A.txt and B.txt content does not have the same line number, and means a.txt record may be in random position. 

i tried your solution but it did'nt work, apparently FNR==NR compare if the record is on the same line am i right? any ways thanks

Comment: @Hazman The order of te lines in the two files does not matter, but I ssee your updated question and will amend my answer ASAP.

Comment: Nah, i was wrong, i forgot to remove something in my A.txt. Your solution work perfectly for me. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Thanks so much sir with detailed explanation as well, i tried doing many days already by searching around the forum, but still can't make it the way i want, and yours only using one line :D
Guess i did learn something here and there, glad i ask a question here, it solved instantly..

Comment: @guest - yes, `data[$1]; next` is all you need and will work in any awk. Using `data[$1]=1` may just take up more memory, depending on how the arrays are implemented.